# Searching words in a file with C++ language

Tags: c++, string, readfile

I'm editing my post with the progress I made so far. Well, what I want to do for now is:

1. Read the text file from the first line without asterics (*), aka the line beginning with number 1, to the end of the file
2. When there is a "blank space" instead of ">sa0" (6th column) put a @ on the variable. And put the next string on the next variable (aka fsa1)
3. Print this to the user line by line.

The code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line, netlist;
    int address, fout, fin;
    string name, type, fsa0, fsa1;

    cout << "Wich Netlist you want to use?" << endl;
    cin >> netlist;

    ifstream file(netlist.c_str());

        if (file.is_open())
        {
             do{

                getline(file, line);

             } while ( line[0] == '*' );


                file >> address >> name >> type >> fout >> fin >> fsa0;
                if (fsa0 != ">sa0") { fsa1 = fsa0; fsa0 = "@"; } else { file >> fsa1; }
                cout << address <<  " " << name << " " << type << " " << fout << " " << fin << " " << fsa0 << " " << fsa1 << endl;



        } else { cout << "File not found" << endl; }

             file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Problems Found:

1. Not showing the first line after the last line with astherisc.
2. Not showing all the lines just the second one.

Text File im trying to read:

```
*c17 iscas example (to test conversion program only)
*---------------------------------------------------
*
*
*  total number of lines in the netlist ..............    17
*  simplistically reduced equivalent fault set size =     22
*        lines from primary input  gates .......     5
*        lines from primary output gates .......     2
*        lines from interior gate outputs ......     4
*        lines from **     3 ** fanout stems ...     6
*
*        avg_fanin  =  2.00,     max_fanin  =  2
*        avg_fanout =  2.00,     max_fanout =  2
*
*
*
*
*
    1     1gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    2     2gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    3     3gat inpt    2   0 >sa0 >sa1
    8     8fan from     3gat      >sa1
    9     9fan from     3gat      >sa1
    6     6gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    7     7gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
   10    10gat nand    1   2      >sa1
     1     8
   11    11gat nand    2   2 >sa0 >sa1
     9     6
   14    14fan from    11gat      >sa1
   15    15fan from    11gat      >sa1
   16    16gat nand    2   2 >sa0 >sa1
     2    14
   20    20fan from    16gat      >sa1
   21    21fan from    16gat      >sa1
   19    19gat nand    1   2      >sa1
    15     7
   22    22gat nand    0   2 >sa0 >sa1
    10    20
   23    23gat nand    0   2 >sa0 >sa1
    21    19
```

And, another thing, can you guys give me some tips on what to do with these lines only with two integers, like the last one?

Thank you all. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: `||` does not work the way you think so `string gatesearch = "and" || "or" || "nand" || "nor" || "not" || "xor";` and `if (netlist == c17 || c432 || c499 || c880 || c1355 || c1908 || c2670 || c3540 || c5315 || c6288 || c75582)` are wrong.

Comment: ***string INPUT[]; // Im not sure the size*** Use a vector or possibly a list.

Comment: ***string gatesearch = "and" || "or" || "nand" || "nor" || "not" || "xor";*** I would use an enum instead if strings for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least IMO, you're approaching this the wrong way. I'd start by reading a line of input. Then check how many items there are on that line. Then parse the items in the line appropriately.

Unless you're absolutely set on doing this in pure C++ on your own, something like AWK or yacc will make the job tremendously easier.

If you do insist on doing it without a parser generator or similar, you could at least use regular expressions to help out quite a bit.